# Godaddy DNS records issue

Tags: dns

DNS ping doesn't reach our server for example:

```
ping clouddir1231.com
```

gives correct server IP in return but

```
ping abc.clouddir1231.com
```

gives same return without reaching our server as we have a docker service listening 0.0.0.0:53 for those subdomain resolution ping to log but nothing is received

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. But besides that `ping` is not the tool to use to troubleshoot DNS problems, `dig` is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to contact your provider about this issue. Please make sure you have pointed your domain to correct name server.